# c fwrite() writing to a file with only one of the struct variable?

Tags: c

This function is supposed to get a parameter as the pointer of a file and put all file into the struct anagram, then write it to another file. Right now the data only contains a.word, but it suppose to containst a.sorted too? I have check the a.sorted using printf
and it printf out the correct data, but why its not writing to the data file?
It still cant get the a.sorted even if i increase the count of the frwite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "anagrams.h"
#define SIZE 80


   //struct
struct anagram {
    char word[SIZE];
    char sorted[SIZE];
};


void buildDB ( const char *const dbFilename ){

FILE *dict, *anagramsFile;
struct anagram a;

//check if dict and anagram.data are open
errno=0;
dict= fopen(dbFilename, "r");

if(errno!=0) {
perror(dbFilename);
exit(1);
}

errno=0;

anagramsFile = fopen(anagramDB,"wb");

char word[SIZE];
char *pos;
int i=0;

while(fgets(word, SIZE, dict) !=NULL){

//get ripe of the '\n'
pos=strchr(word, '\n');
    *pos = '\0';

strncpy(a.word,word,sizeof(word));
//lowercase word
int j=0;
while (word[j])
  {
    tolower(word[j]);
    j++;
  }

/* sort array using qsort functions */ 
qsort(word,strlen(word), 1, charCompare);

strncpy(a.sorted,word,sizeof(word));
//printf(a);

fwrite(&a,1,strlen(word)+1,anagramsFile);

i++;
}
fclose(dict);
fclose(anagramsFile);

}
```

it suppose to contains data with a.sorted for example "10th 01ht"
data: [image]

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite(&a,1,strlen(word)+1,anagramsFile);` should have been `fwrite(a.sorted,1,strlen(a.sorted)+1,anagramsFile);` I assume the declaration of sorted as `char sorted[SOME_LEN];`

Comment: The problem is I want both a.word and a.sorted write to the file, not just one of them

Comment: Can you just post the structure `struct anagram`

Comment: Then you can write the whole structure into the file `fwrite(&a,1,sizeof(struct anagram),anagramsFile);` instead writing only the length of the words.

Comment: yes tried that, but it does not contain the a.sorted which i dont understand

Comment: You can `memset` before writing something to the structure. Try `memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));` after `int i=0`